# nested sql JOIN

Tags: sql, nested

I have only the first table ( fi.id, fi.user_id, fi.amount, fi.currency, fi.created_at) as an output with the following code. Could you tell me why JOIN is not effective please.
Thank you for your help
Mahfoud

```
 SELECT fi.id, fi.user_id, fi.amount, fi.currency, fi.created_at
     FROM fund_infos fi
      JOIN (SELECT ii.id, ii.user_id, ii.first_kana_name, ii.last_kana_name
    FROM individual_infos ii) Y ON fi.user_id = Y.id
   ORDER BY fi.id
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Shouldn't be any problem performance-wise for most dbms products. (Somewhat harder to read.)

Comment: Unrelated, but: `JOIN (SELECT ii.id, ii.user_id, ii.first_kana_name, ii.last_kana_name
    FROM individual_infos ii) y ON ...` can be simplified to `join individual_infos y ON ...`

Comment: Thank you so much. I am using pg Admin.

Answer (score 0):

You are only returning values from table `fund_infos` as part of the select.

To output columns from Y, specify the column in your select:

```
 SELECT fi.id, fi.user_id, fi.amount, fi.currency, fi.created_at,
        Y.user_id, Y.first_kana_name, Y.last_kana_name -- You can also use Y.* here
 FROM fund_infos fi
 JOIN (
      SELECT ii.id, ii.user_id, ii.first_kana_name, ii.last_kana_name
      FROM individual_infos ii
      ) Y 
   ON fi.user_id = Y.id
 ORDER BY fi.id
```

Comment: Thank you so much all. I will try it as soon as I go back to my company and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all columns you want in the `SELECT`.  As important, you don't need a subquery to do this:

```
SELECT fi.id, fi.user_id, fi.amount, fi.currency, fi.created_at,
       ii.user_id, ii.first_kana_name, ii.last_kana_name
FROM fund_infos fi JOIN
     individual_infos ii
     ON fi.user_id = ii.id
ORDER BY fi.id;
```

Notes:

- You don't need to include `ii.id` in the `SELECT` because you already having `fi.user_id`.
- You probably want to rename on of the `user_id` fields, so they have different names.
- Are you sure the `JOIN` conditions are correct?  It is odd that both tables have `id`s and `user_id`s.

Answer (score 0):

use join

```
SELECT fi.id, fi.user_id, fi.amount, fi.currency, fi.created_at, ii.id, ii.first_kana_name,
       ii.last_kana_name
FROM fund_infos fi
     JOIN individual_infos ii ON fi.user_id = ii.user_id
ORDER BY fi.id;
```